# How to implement desktop push notifications in an Angular 7 web application supporting Safari?

Tags: angular, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push-api

I implemented this feature using Firebase Cloud Messaging. But it is not working in Safari since it lack Push API support ( which the FCM is built upon). Have somebody implemented it in a proper manner to support all 3 major browsers?

Comment: Hi  Midhun! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please share a Minimal Complete Verifiable(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  Example? You can share one using StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular).

Comment: @programoholic  Thank you. The implementation requires a back end to push the notification.  I did it using  (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/) and (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client). An MCVE might take time to create. I 'll do it by the end of the day. And I assume a push can be triggered using a curl request.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Nodejs then you can go for node-notifier. Easiest method to implement notification service.**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier

```
npm i node-notifier

const notifier = require('node-notifier');
// String
notifier.notify('Message');

// Object
notifier.notify({
  title: 'My notification',
  message: 'Hello, there!'
});
```